# Popup window in Silverlight 4 and Prism

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, prism-4

In Silverlight and PRISM, what is the good way to open a popup child window which is in one Module by passing a parameter from a ViewModel in different Module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a common interface/class known to both module, called IChildWindowService, register the IChildWindowServe/ChildWindowService in the bootstrapper.

```
//Highly simplified version
//Can be improved by window reuse, parameter options, stronger eventing
public class ChildWindowService : IChildWindowService
{
    public ChildWindowService(IServiceLocator container)
    {
        _container = container;
    } 
    public void Show<TViewModel>(TViewModel viewModel = null, Action<TViewModel, bool?> callBack = null) where TViewModel is IViewModel
    {
        var viewName = typeof(TViewModel).Name.Replace("Model", string.Empty);
        // In bootstrapper register all instances of IView or register each view one by one
        var view = _container.GetInstance<IView>(viewName);
        viewModel = viewModel ?? _container.GetInstance<TViewModel>();
        view.DataContext = viewModel;
        var window = new ChildWindow();
        window.Content = view;
        var handler = (s,e) => { window.Close(); }
        viewModel.RequestClose += handler; 
        view.Closed += (s,e) => { viewModel.RequestClose -= handler; }
        // In silverlight all windows show as Modal, if you are using a third party you can make a decision here
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Create a common CompositePresentationEvent, this event will pass the parameters from point a to point b

`public class OpenChildWindowWithParameters : CompositePresentationEvent<ParamEventArgs>{}`

The ViewModel in Module A raises the Event.
The Controller in Module B registers and reacts to the Event.
The Controller in Module B takes the child window service as a dependency.
When the event is raised the Controller will create the VM in Module B and pass the parameters to it, from the event, it will also use the Service to display a ChildWindow.

Comment: Can you post the code for ChildWindowService. I think i got your other points.